# Measuring and Exporting System Performance on Android Phones in Battery Drainage Experiment

Tags: android, battery

I am working on an experiment that requires measuring battery drainage and system performance impact for an android app. The app has multiple features that can be turned on and off individually, hence allowing me to measure the impact of each component independently.

The app is a connectivity monitoring tool that gathers information about signal strength, performs QoS tests for both mobile and wi-fi connections, logs information about call duration and GPS info, etc.

To measure the power consumption (hence battery drainage), I will be running the phone using the [Monsoon Power Monitor](http://www.msoon.com/LabEquipment/PowerMonitor/) which will be connected to a PC to collect the required data. I will be establishing a baseline first for each Android phone that I will use for the experiment and then perform the app component measurements.

However, I still haven't figured out the best way to measure the system performance metrics (Memory Usage, CPU Load, etc...) in a way that can help me fulfill the following requirements:

- External Measurement: the measurement needs to be independent of my app. That is, I don't want to add code to log system performance information from within my app.
- Exportable: the measurements need to be associated with time and can also be exported for analysis alongside the measurements from the Monsoon Power Monitor.
- Rooting the Phone: the method of measuring phone's system performance metrics CANNOT be one that requires rooting of the phone. The environment that is simulated is a typical end user, who usually wouldn't root their phone.

From my understanding, there is no way to do an external (totally hardware external) method to gather the performance information. Hence, the next best method is to use another app and establish a base line for that app. However, considering the aforementioned requirements, what application (or potentially a different method) would help me achieve the described objective?

Thanks!

Comment: "External Measurement: the measurement needs to be independent of my app" -- by definition, that is not possible. You will need an app to collect this data (and export it, per your second bullet); therefore, it cannot be independent of your app, even if this is for some reason a *second* app. "Hence, the next best method is to use another app" -- IMHO, the next-best method is to have your main app perform the data collection. Having two apps further perturbs the results, particularly since these app(s) will be unusual with respect to what a regular user runs.

Comment: Also, is there a particular reason you are using Monsoon Power Monitor instead of a Qualcomm MDP with Trepn? Trepn and an MDP would handle all your performance metrics *and* give you better power analysis than you will get by measuring things right from the battery terminals.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The issue with allowing my app to collect the data is that it will affect the independent performance of the feature. I want to be able to treat the app environment as a blackbox.

Comment: Qualcomm MDP with Trepn looks interesting. I will explore that option for comparative reasons. However, my aim is to abstract the battery status by avoiding the need to create battery state profile for each phone I will be running the experiment on. If I used the Monsoon Power Monitor (which will power the phone bypassing the battery because it acts as a power supply as well), then I am assuming an ideal battery state and can arrive at objective power consumption conclusions with ideal constant current and voltage. This will take away the hassle of dealing with battery supply volatility.